# Add class to field parent with a preprocess hook in a custom module?

Tags: theming, hooks

### Background:

I would like to alter the classes that are added to a rendered field in Drupal 9 in a custom module. I'm trying to use `hook_preprocess_field` and I'm not sure if this will work or if there is a better alternative.

based on:
https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2017-03-31/add-class-to-field-in-drupal-8

#### I have the following:

```
function my_module_preprocess_field__field_pricing_grid_items(&$vars)
{
  
  foreach(array_keys($vars['items']) as $delta)
  {
    $vars['items'][$delta]['attributes']->setAttribute('class', 'my-class');
  }
}
```

This works for adding a class but I can't figure out how to add a class to the parent div. [image]

#### Result

```
 <div class ="field__items">
         <div class ="field__item CUSTOM-CLASS"></div>
      </div>
```

#### Desired result:

```
 <div class ="field__items CUSTOM-CLASS">
     <div class ="field__item></div>
  </div>
```

### Questions:

1. How can I add a class to the parent div? Is that possible with this hook?
2. Would an alternative approach of maybe overriding the field with a template in my module work? The theme template would be `field--field-pricing-grid-items.html.twig` Is there a way to override the theme with a module?
3. If neither of these approaches make sense what would be a possible way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

I was going with the wrong approach.

What worked:

I needed to use `hook_theme` in my `/my_module/my_module.module` file

```
function MY_MODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'field__field_pricing_grid_items' => [
      'base hook' => 'field',
      'path' => $path . '/templates/field',
    ],
  ];
}
```

then it was easy to override `field.html.twig` with `/my_module/templates/field/field--field-pricing-grid-items.html.twig`